# Transforming an Elasticsearch query string to JSON query

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm unsure how to append to an Elasticsearch query string such that there is no risk of query injection. I'm wondering if I need to transform the query string into a JSON query so that I have better control in appending to the query. Does anyone know if this is the best approach or if there is a better alternative?

I need this because I'm accepting untrusted Elasticsearch queries over HTTP using query string format.

My backend is Java, but I'll work with any language examples provided.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you're trying to achieve and what you'd like to avoid ?

Comment: @Val Requests look like https://..../path/to/resource?search=<elasticsearch-query-string>. I grab that ES query string and need to concatenate some extra stuff, but I can't do that with string concat because it opens up injection risks. So I need to understand how to inject-protect the ES query string API-side - or transform the query string into an ES JSON query API-side so that I can manipulate it safely.

Comment: Can you give a concrete example, please?

Comment: @Val sorry, I don't know what you mean by concrete example. I'm trying to find out I can do this so I can write it. There's no code yet.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what kind of injection attacks you're afraid of? If that problematic came up, it must mean you've thought about it. Can you give a practical example of what you're trying to solve?

Comment: Just regular nosql injection. For the same reason that one shouldn't perform server-side string concatenation on sql queries, neither should they on nonsql queries. E.g. user supplies "username:*)OR(username:joe.bloggs", I concat "(" + userquery + ") AND account:12345678" giving "(username:*)OR(username:joe.bloggs) AND account:12345678" which will return all users in ES including those not in their account - standard inject problem.

Comment: The first rule to prevent injection is that you should never blindly accept user-input data without cleaning it up first. If you know who the user is, then you should blacklist the fields he's not allowed to provide (i.e. `username`) and add that constraint yourself

Comment: Hence the question, what's the best approach with ES queries. Actual SQL queries are never accepted in normal design direct from end users. Not so for ES queries. It's normal to allow end users to enter/supply potentially large queries. So if there's no existing mechanism built into ES client libraries to protect against injection, how should it be done? The only option I can think of is to transform the input query to an ES JSON query and then append the relevant JSON restrictions (i.e. account: 12345678). How to do this?

Comment: May I ask why you need to "accept untrusted Elasticsearch queries over HTTP" if you have sensitive data that should not leak? Sounds like a design conflict to me...

Comment: I'm building a technical application, but I've also built non-technical applications that have allowed ES queries to be entered by end users. It's not uncommon and one of the intended use cases of ES.

Comment: I may have found something here: https://github.com/elefana/es-query-string-parser/issues/1